# How to List all fields of table with checkbox when a particular tablename selected from dropdownlist in mvc3?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to get all table fields List along with checkboxes when a particular table name is selected in dropdownlist.

I have done coding to get all tablenames in dropdownlist that is

```
public ActionResult Dropdown()
    {

        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        using (var etm = new MovieDBEntities())
        {
         results = etm.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("SELECT name FROM sys.tables ORDER BY name").ToList();
        }

        ViewBag.results = results;
        return View();
    }
```

please help me..

Comment: Question is very vague. Please put more effort into explaining your issues

Comment: Thing i need is i have got all tablenames in a dropdownlist and On a button click i need to List all fields of table with checkbox besides on each field when i selecte tablename from dropdownlist

Comment: if issue is in client then display html and explain what you want from html. If issue is at server then explain that. Can't make sense of your issue without a far better explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.fetch name and object id of tables

```
using (var etm = new MovieDBEntities())
    {
     results = etm.ExecuteStoreQuery<Dictionary<string,string>>("SELECT name,object_id FROM sys.tables ORDER BY name");
    }
```

2.Write code to send object id to new Action Method

```
ActionResult GetColumns(int object_id)
{
     List<string> cols = new List<string>();
        using (var etm = new dbStudentsInfoEntities())
        {
          cols = etm.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("SELECT name FROM sys.columns where object_id=" + object_id + " ORDER BY name").AsQueryable().ToList();
        }
ViewBag.Output=cols ;
}
```

3.on View Page

```
 foreach (string a in ViewBag.Output)
{
 <input type="checkbox" value="@a" name="chk" /> @a
}
```